# Is it possible to create a document template in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to add many documents to my firestore database and they all need the exact same fields. Is it possible to create a "template" so I don't need to keep adding the same fields to each document I make?

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a document template in Firestore. If you need this, most devs create a simple administrative app, and you could of course also consider using one of the 3rd party content management systems that support Firestore.